# Visual Studio C++ - std::map insertion failing

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, stl, visual-studio-2013

I have the following piece of code that works in GCC.

```
//StyleEditor.h
typedef std::set<HWND> PanelSet;

class DLL_EXPORT StyleEditor
{
public:
StyleEditor(HWND mainWnd, std::wstring instanceName);
~StyleEditor();
int Edit(std::wstring styleName);
BOOL DoInitDialog(HWND hwndDlg, bool updatePos);
BOOL DoCommand(HWND hwndDlg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL DoNotify(HWND hwndDlg, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL DoColourChooser(COLORREF* colour, HWND hwndDlg);
BOOL DoLoad(HWND hwndDlg);
BOOL DoSwitch(HWND hwndDlg);
void DoSaveAs(HWND hwndDlg);
static INT_PTR CALLBACK StyleEditorDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LPCTSTR GetTemplate();

private:
std::map< HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> > panelMap;
std::wstring tmpFile, instanceName;
RECT colourRect;
COLORREF colourBackground, colourForeground, colourSelected, colourFrame, colourFont;
COLORREF colourFrom, colourTo, colourBorder;
HWND mainWnd, toolWnd;
GUIINFO guiInfo, origGuiInfo, defaultGuiInfo;
std::wstring style, font, origStyle;
HBITMAP hbmColourBackground, hbmColourForeground, hbmColourSelected, hbmColourFrame, hbmColourFont;
HBITMAP hbmColourFrom, hbmColourTo, hbmColourBorder;
std::wstring DoSaveStyle(HWND hwndDlg, std::wstring fileName);
BOOL DoDefaults(HWND hwndDlg);
void BuildPanelMap(HWND hwndDlg);
void ClearPanelMap();
void ShowPanel(HTREEITEM panel);
HTREEITEM hitemOpacity, hitemColor, hitemGradient, hitemMisc;
};
```

---

```
//StyleEditor.cpp
TVINSERTSTRUCT tvInsert;

tvInsert.hParent = NULL;
tvInsert.hInsertAfter = TVI_ROOT;
tvInsert.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
tvInsert.item.pszText = (WCHAR*)TEXT("Opacity");
hitemOpacity = TreeView_InsertItem(treeWnd, &tvInsert);
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, PanelSet*>(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
```

In Visual Studio 2013, it bombs out during compiling:

```
1>  StyleEditor.cpp
1>d:\programming\emergedesktop\emergedesktophgtip\source\emergestyleengine\styleeditor.h(90): warning C4251: 'StyleEditor::panelMap' : class 'std::map<HTREEITEM,std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'StyleEditor'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=HTREEITEM
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>
1>          ]

<snip - a lot more of the same warning>

1>d:\programming\emergedesktop\emergedesktophgtip\source\emergestyleengine\styleeditor.cpp(491): error C2664: 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<HTREEITEM,PanelSet *>' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=HTREEITEM
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>
1>  ,            _Pr=std::less<HTREEITEM >
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const HTREEITEM ,std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>>>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Kty=HTREEITEM
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'std::pair<HTREEITEM,PanelSet *>' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=HTREEITEM
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

<snip - more of the same error>
```

I fixed the warnings by shifting the DLL_EXPORTS to the individual methods being exported instead of the class itself:

```
class StyleEditor
{
public:
DLL_EXPORT StyleEditor(HWND mainWnd, std::wstring instanceName);
DLL_EXPORT ~StyleEditor();
DLL_EXPORT int Edit(std::wstring styleName);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoInitDialog(HWND hwndDlg, bool updatePos);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoCommand(HWND hwndDlg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoNotify(HWND hwndDlg, LPARAM lParam);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoColourChooser(COLORREF* colour, HWND hwndDlg);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoLoad(HWND hwndDlg);
DLL_EXPORT BOOL DoSwitch(HWND hwndDlg);
DLL_EXPORT void DoSaveAs(HWND hwndDlg);
DLL_EXPORT static INT_PTR CALLBACK StyleEditorDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
DLL_EXPORT LPCTSTR GetTemplate();

private:
std::map< HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> > panelMap;
std::wstring tmpFile, instanceName;
RECT colourRect;
COLORREF colourBackground, colourForeground, colourSelected, colourFrame, colourFont;
COLORREF colourFrom, colourTo, colourBorder;
HWND mainWnd, toolWnd;
GUIINFO guiInfo, origGuiInfo, defaultGuiInfo;
std::wstring style, font, origStyle;
HBITMAP hbmColourBackground, hbmColourForeground, hbmColourSelected, hbmColourFrame, hbmColourFont;
HBITMAP hbmColourFrom, hbmColourTo, hbmColourBorder;
std::wstring DoSaveStyle(HWND hwndDlg, std::wstring fileName);
BOOL DoDefaults(HWND hwndDlg);
void BuildPanelMap(HWND hwndDlg);
void ClearPanelMap();
void ShowPanel(HTREEITEM panel);
HTREEITEM hitemOpacity, hitemColor, hitemGradient, hitemMisc;
};
```

But VS is still erroring out on the `panelMap.insert` lines in `StyleEditor.cpp`. I've experimented with various iterations of `std::shared_ptr` in the call, like this:

```
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>>(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>>(hitemOpacity, std::make_shared<PanelSet>(new PanelSet))); //appears to work at first, but errors in VC's memory header show up instead
```

and I'm out of ideas at this point. I'm not even sure how I'd go about searching for this error since the error message is so long and messy. I'd appreciate any advice on what exactly is wrong with this code (keeping in mind that GCC doesn't have a problem with it) and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be trying the obvious (?) thing.

This is your map

```
std::map< HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> > panelMap;
```

and you've tried

```
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, PanelSet*>(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
```

and

```
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, std::shared_ptr<PanelSet>>(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
```

but for some reason not this

```
panelMap.insert(std::pair<HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet>>(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem in this case, but here's a suggestion to avoid problems like this in the future.

First I would declare a typedef for the map

```
typedef std::map< HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> > PanelMapType;
```

then use the `value_type` typedef that every map has when you insert

```
panelMap.insert(PanelMapType::value_type(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));
```

This way you ensure that the type you are inserting to the map is the correct one. And also if there is an error caused by a type mismatch it will reference your code, instead of code in the guts of the `map::insert` function.

Comment: I actually did try the one you suggested; it gave an error as well, which leads me to believe that shared_ptr<PanelSet> isn't being treated the same as PanelSet*. I'll give the typedef a shot though, thanks.

Comment: @computerfreaker Are you seeing the difference between `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a difference. And the typedef you suggested is failing as well, fwiw.

Comment: @computerfreaker The simple explanation for your error is that on g++ the two types are the same but on VS they are not (I don't know if this is true). In modern code you should not be using the tr1 version anyway.

Comment: @computerfreaker What does the error say with the typedef version?

Comment: @computerfreaker I'm perplexed. How about trying this `PanelMapType::value_type tmp; tmp.first = hitemOpacity; tmp.second = new PanelSet; panelMap.insert(tmp);`? Just trying to break things down to get a handle on what is causing the error.

Comment: how about std::make_pair?

Comment: I couldn't get a compile error because it was too busy complaining about assigning a value to a `const` in `tmp.first=hitemOpacity;`. But Intellisense gave me this; `Error: no operator '=' matches these operands. Operand types are std::shared_ptr<PanelSet> = PanelSet*`. Looks like I have some casting to do? (I'm just uncertain if casting a normal pointer to a `shared_ptr` is considered a good idea.)

Comment: @thermite `panelMap.insert(std::make_pair(hitemOpacity, new PanelSet));` gives http://pastebin.com/EX0Sy8yT

Comment: Tried a `static_cast` too. `std::pair < HTREEITEM, std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> > tmp; tmp.first = hitemOpacity; tmp.second = static_cast<std::tr1::shared_ptr<PanelSet> >(new PanelSet); panelMap.insert(tmp);` It compiles successfully. Any idea why that might be working when nothing else would?